# Intel Video problem

Tags: intel-graphics

I am new in Ubuntu and have 14.04
I tried to setup display resolution more than 800x600 but probably made a mistake. I expected to have  1366x768 or 1920 x 1080 with Samsung S27E390H, but now I have 1024x768 and wrong packages installed.

1)

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

2)

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       61.0* 
   800x600        61.0  
   640x480        60.0  
  1366x768 (0x229)   85.2MHz
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock   47.8KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.9Hz
```

3)

```
    lspci -vnn
    00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:190f] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8694]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>

    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1912] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8694]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
        Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
...............
```

Could anybody help me, please, uninstall wrong and install proper? )

4)

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "VGA-1"
```

Comment: "I tried to setup display resolution " what did you exactly do?

Comment: It is difficult to say exactly now) I tried to install different drivers, I think)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xrandr` to set needed resolution if you fail to do so with xorg:

```
cvt 1920 1080 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync   #those numbers may vary depending on your screen
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

To make changes peristant you can add model line to xorg file, or create bash script that will run on start of the system.

```
#!/bin/bash
cvt 1920 1080 60
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

hope this helps

As for unmet dependencies, you can try uninstalling driver first, installing dependencies then installing driver after it.

Comment: The result is in part 4) of my top post. Without success(

Comment: Also got failure for second and third lines under new install of 16.04.2 using Intel on-chip graphics controller and HDMI output.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying out Ubuntu 16.04LTS on my Acer Aspire 5630 laptop with Intel Mobile integrated graphics 940GM/GMS 943/940GML. I could only reach 1024x768 resolution and xrandr would not detect gamma or any higher resolution. After trying many suggestions from the net, I simply installed the xserver-xorg-video-intel package and was then able to use the native 1280x800 resolution. It also cured a booting problem, as previously I could only boot using recovery mode and resuming boot, sometimes having to resume boot twice.